# Javascript Custom tabs add to code: hide content if tab is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

i try to add dynamic content to tabs and hide content if tab is empty

**html code**

```
<ul id="tabs">
    <li><a href="#" name="#tab1">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" name="#tab2">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" name="#tab3">Three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" name="#tab4">Four</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="content_tabs">
    <div id="tab1">content 1</div>
    <div id="tab2">content 2</div>
    <div id="tab3">content 3</div>
    <div id="tab4">content 4</div>
</div>
```

**js code**

```
function resetTabs(){
    jQuery("#content_tabs > div").hide(); //Hide all content
    jQuery("#tabs a").attr("id",""); //Reset id's      
}

var myUrl = window.location.href; //get URL
var myUrlTab = myUrl.substring(myUrl.indexOf("#")); // For mywebsite. com/tabs.html#tab2, myUrlTab = #tab2     
var myUrlTabName = myUrlTab.substring(0,4); // For the above example, myUrlTabName = #tab

jQuery(function(){
    jQuery("#content_tabs > div").hide(); // Initially hide all content
    jQuery("#tabs li:first a").attr("id","current"); // Activate first tab
    jQuery("#content_tabs > div:first").fadeIn(); // Show first tab content

    jQuery("#tabs a").on("click",function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (jQuery(this).attr("id") == "current"){ //detection for current tab
         return       
        }
        else{             
        resetTabs();
        jQuery(this).attr("id","current"); // Activate this
        jQuery(jQuery(this).attr('name')).fadeIn(); // Show content for current tab
        }
    });

    for (i = 1; i <= $("#tabs li").length; i++) {
      if (myUrlTab == myUrlTabName + i) {
          resetTabs();
          jQuery("a[name='"+myUrlTab+"']").attr("id","current"); // Activate url tab
          jQuery(myUrlTab).fadeIn(); // Show url tab content        
      }
    }
});
```

**beauty css**

```
#tabs {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#tabs li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 -15px 0 0;
}

#tabs a {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 40px;
  height: 0; 
  line-height: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  border-right: 30px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 30px solid #3D3D3D;
  border-bottom-color: #777\9;
  opacity: .3;
  filter: alpha(opacity=30);      
}

#tabs a:hover,
#tabs a:focus {
  border-bottom-color: #2ac7e1;
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}

#tabs a:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

#tabs #current {
  z-index: 3;
  border-bottom-color: #3d3d3d;
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);     
}
```

**here demo**
http://jsfiddle.net/uVNFp/95/

appreciate if someone know how I do to hide content if tab is empty

Thanks

Comment: Why would use use an id for the current one. You should not be using the id, but a css class. I also thing your names are illegal, You should be using html5 data attributes or use the href and link to the hash like links do.

Comment: code isn't mine, seemed clean, but what you mean with the names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/tdf22/1/

Changes from your original fiddle:

- Removed contents of `<div id="tab2">`.
- Added the following.

> ```
> $("#content_tabs > div:empty").each(function() {
>     $("#tabs > li").eq($(this).index()).hide();
> });
> ```

**EDIT:**

In response to your comment about blank space, I created this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/tdf22/3/

In this one, I:

- added the following jQuery custom expression

> ```
> $.expr[":"].emptyOrWhiteSpace = function(obj){
>   var $this = $(obj);
>   return ($.trim($this.html()) === "");
> };
> ```

- and changed this line

  $("#content_tabs > div:empty").each(function() {
- to this

  $("#content_tabs > div:emptyOrWhiteSpace").each(function() {

Comment: thank you very much user704808, the fiddle work perfect, now in my wp theme don't work, surely I'm too tired but this is the solution. thanks

Comment: my dynammic content create a blank space for this don't work in my wp theme, i try to fix blank space in wp

Answer (score 1):

Gustavo, this is just a quick answer I put together so that you have something working. This can be accomplished in a more professional manner. http://jsfiddle.net/tdf22/8/

I simply added this at the bottom of your javascript:

```
var tabs = $('#tabs li');
for (var i=0; i<tabs.length; ++i) {
  if (tabs[i].style.display !== 'none') {
    tabs[i].firstChild.id = 'current'; 
    $('#tab'+(i+1)).show();
    return false;
  }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var El = document.getElementById("El"); //replace
If(El.hasChildNodes()) {
      El.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        El.style.display = "none";
    }
```

Comment: This is correct as far as it goes, but does not show how to hide the tab (li) when the corresponding content (div) is empty.